# Play Multiple Songs On Media Player

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

How can I reference more than one song on the same button click and not writing `Mediaplayer.create()` again and again for every song?

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context,R.raw.jeenajeena);                        
            mediaPlayer.start();
}
```

Comment: did the answer solve your issue?

Comment: yes sir it solved thank u very much for your help

Comment: You can mark it as the correct answer then

Answer (score 2):

Add your files in array and play them one by one.

```
int[] medias = {
    R.raw.song1, R.raw.song2, R.raw.song3
};
```

Now create a loop that plays through them one by one.

```
private void playSongs(final int next){
    if(next>=medias.length)return;
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context,medias[next]);
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            playSongs(next+1);
        }
    });
    mediaPlayer.start();
}
```

Now you should call this on your onClick of the button

```
playSongs(0);
```